# Get logs of github action when fails

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a github action to catch when a build fails:

```
run-if-failed:
    runs-on: macos-11
    needs: [ sonar, main ]
    if: always() && (needs.sonar.result == 'failure' || needs.main.result == 'failure')
    steps:
      - if: ${{ failure() }}
        run: gh run view --log-failed
      - name: Needs context
        env:
          NEEDS_CONTEXT: ${{ toJSON(needs.main.result) }}
        run: echo "::notice file=Error,title=What Went Wrong::$NEEDS_CONTEXT"
```

however I am unable to truly see what the failure is with `$NEEDS_CONTEXT`

Is there a way to display the failure logs like it does in actions tab of github?

Comment: Perhaps try [downloading the logs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflow-runs#download-workflow-run-logs)?